# Algolia - Delete Objects Where ObjectID is NOT in?

Tags: php, algolia

Is it possible to make a code that will delete all Algolia objects in a index that are NOT in an array of objects.

To explain it better, then it would work like this if it was MySQL:

```
DELETE * FROM someIndex WHERE `ObjectID` NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Currently I can only seem to find a way to delete the objects that are in an array:

```
$index->deleteObjects([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this isn't something you can do. Algolia does have a [deleteByQuery](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/indexing/#delete-by-query) method which gives you more flexibility because you can pass [filters](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/parameters/filters/#filters), but there is no NOT IN filter.

A solution would be to query your main database that mirrors the index and get the IDs from there, then pass them to Algolia.

Comment: I was able to do this using the filters and another parameter.

Comment: @MarkTopper so... what was your solution?  You asked the question and it sounds like you figured it out, but you didn't post anything.

Comment: @bsplosion, I went with a script that updated another parameter, and then a DELETE that checked for that parameter rather than the ObjectID. I don't have the exact code with me, sorry.